# React Native - Show Splash Screen after redirecting to 'Home'

Tags: react-native

I am redirecting to my default page (initialRouteName), which is "sign-in", after logging out. I'd like to show the splash screen again (defined in app.json), just as if the app was first started. Any ideas?

app.json:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash_screen_image.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#2799E0"
    },
 ...
```

app.js:

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import MainScreen from './screens/ MainScreen';
import SignIn from './screens/SignInScreen';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
setTimeout(SplashScreen.hideAsync, 3000);

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="sign-in"
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen name="sign-in">
            {(props) => (
              <SignIn setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
            )}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name="main-screen">
            {(props) => (
              <MainScreen
                setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}
                isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
              />
            )}
          </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```